# rendering blank white box on the screen (Android studio, Mac)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, rendering

While working with Android studio, weird rectangles are appearing suddenly.
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t18fn.jpg), once I quit android studio those rectangles are getting disappear.

solutions I tried: restarted Android studio, reinstalled android studio
but nothing worked.

any light on this problem would be highly appreciatable.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in the latest Beta version (Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 RC 1). You can switch to It as a temporary solution.